# recursive function in node is running out of memory -- tried process.nextTick, but still fails

Tags: node.js, recursion

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

Here is the code. Note I added the `process.nextTick` to make the recursive call as suggested in another post, but I still get the memory error.

```
function req(url){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request({
            url: url
        }, function (err, res, body) {
            if (err) {
                console.trace(err);
                return reject(err);
            } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
                err = new Error("Unexpected status code: " + res.statusCode);
                err.res = res;
                console.trace(err);
                return reject(err);
            }

            resolve(body);
        });
    });
}


function getNextUrl(url){
    var page = provider.results.page(url);

    nextPages.push(url);

    req(url)
        .then(function (body) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body)
                , $profileUrls = provider.results.profileUrls($)
                , nextUrl = provider.results.next($, url);

            async.eachLimit($profileUrls, argv.concurrent, function(el, cb){
                var $el = $(el)
                    , profileUrl = provider.results.profileUrl($, $el);

                getProfileUrl(profileUrl, url)
                    .then(function(body){
                        cb(null);
                    }, function(err){
                        console.trace(err);
                    });
            }, function(err){
                if ( err ) {
                    return console.trace(err);
                }

                console.log('Done with profile urls.'.info);

                //here is the recursive call
                process.nextTick(function(){
                    getNextUrl(nextUrl);
                });
            });
        }, function(err){
            console.trace(err);
        });
}


getNextUrl(startUrl);
```

This code runs fine with about 10k urls, but if I bump it up to 20k, I get this error. I need it to run on a heck of a lot more than 20k, maybe 200k for starters. I would like this thing to eventually just work on any number without crashing.

When `async.eachLimit` finishes, it calls itself on a new url. I suspect this is the source of the problem. I am collecting a few bits of data in an array of objects, but when I write this JSON to disk, its only about 5mb, and my system has 1gb of ram.

Comment: Try processing them in batches; process 10k, wait until they're done, process another 10k, etc.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but that isn't really a solution to the problem. I'd like to know why this is happening and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, my response to the [related issue](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/500):

> That should be related to [cheerio#263](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/500): URLs are slices of the original document, maintaining them means keeping the entire document in memory. After 20k pages, you'll run out of memory. A fix would be to force V8 to create a copy, eg. by using (" " + url).substr(1).

Comment: Where exactly would I use this `("" + url).substr(1)` hack?

Comment: Probably here: `, nextUrl = provider.results.next($, url);`

Comment: Can you explain this hack? Isn't that just going to give me `ttp://` in `http://.....`?

Comment: V8 (node's JS engine) stores attributes in cheerio's DOM as slices (start & length references regarding the original document). As a result, saving a single attribute forces V8 to keep the entire document in memory.

Comment: The hack forces V8 to create a copy of the attribute. A character is appended in front of the attribute & immediately removed.